# No module named azure.cosmos.cosmos_client

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb, raspberry-pi3, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm getting the next error while running the example python script of azure cosmos db:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CosmosGetStarted.py", line 1, in <module>
    import azure.cosmos.cosmos_client as cosmos_client
ImportError: No module named azure.cosmos.cosmos_client
```

I was trying to do everything according to the next manual:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-python

Answer (score 5):

Install the latest azure-cosmos package:

```
pip3 install --upgrade azure-cosmos
```

and then import the package like this:

```
from azure.cosmos import exceptions, CosmosClient, PartitionKey
```

there are more details in the official package page [here](https://pypi.org/project/azure-cosmos/)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue:

Just call "python3.6 CosmosGetStarted.py" and not "python CosmosGetStarted.py"